# How to execute the same Python scripts in parallel in TestStand?

Tags: python, teststand

I am using TestStand with a setup consists of 2 sockets (DUTs). Each DUT is connected with a serial interface to send/receive datae. Now I have a pyhton script which opens the serial interface and exchange data. The python script uses the Com-Port number as input parameter.

So far the python script works for DUT 1 or DUT2 without any problem. Now I would like to implement and use this python sript in TestStand.

Questions:

- is it possible to use TestStand to execute this python script in parallel?
- if yes, how do I need to setup the TestStand in order to run the test in parallel?

When using the batch model I do have access to both DUTs but the data are not coming in parallel and rather in sequence (first DUT1 then DUT2). So I assume there is something wrong in the setup of TS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do this in parallel in TestStand.

You would want to use the asynchronous function.  Here is an [example](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Code/Run-a-LabVIEW-VI-Asynchronously-from-TestStand/ta-p/3834066).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32783779)